# Pythonic polymorphing parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a little new to Python. I have a case where I am creating geometry in Blender. I'm using an enum to define the types of geometry. Different types of geometry require different initialization parameters. For example, ICOSPHERE needs subdivisions, while UV_SPHERE needs segments and rings.

What is a Pythonic way to write a function to handle this, with essentially a polymorphic list of arguments? To call the function we give it an enum and the appropriate params for that enum, and then  the function uses a switch block or something to handle each type of the enum. I don't want to use function overloading -- I want a single function that handles the various cases.

I guess the params could be a dictionary. This would encapsulate the variable list of params into a single parameter. Is there a better way?

Comment: "I don't want to use function overloading". You're in luck: Python doesn't support function overloading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a suggestion, and is based off of using one function and an enum class.

```py
class Geometry:
    ICOSPHERE = 1
    UV_SPHERE = 2


def blendrFunc(gtype, **kwargs):
    arg1 = kwargs['arg1']

    if gtype == Geometry.ICOSPHERE:
        arg2 = kwargs['arg2']
        icosphere_func(arg1, arg2)

    elif  gtype == Geometry.UV_SPHERE:
        uvsphere_func(arg1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    blendrFunc(Geometry.ICOSPHERE, arg1 = 1, arg2 = (1, 2))

    blendrFunc(Geometry.UV_SPHERE, arg1 = [3, 4])
```

Basically use a key words dictionary for flexible arguments.  Some keywords can be shared between geometry types, or mean different types of objects for different geometries.  Some keywords may be required or not used for other geometries.

You can better handle the arguments by doing something like this.

```py
arg = kwargs.get('arg', None)
if arg is None:
    raise ValueError('UVSPHERE requires arg to be ...')
```

Comment: This is the approach that I meant with "the params could be a dictionary". It definitely works but I wonder what other approaches there might be.

Answer (score 1):

You can write functions to deal with an arbitrary number of arguments, keyword arguments or both. This is done by adding asterisks to the parameter representing the arguments (`*`) or the keyword arguments (`**`).

Arbitrary arguments are taken as a tuple:

```
>>> def func_with_arbitrary_args(*args):
...     print(args)
...     print(type(args))
...     for arg in args:
...         print(arg)

>>> func_with_arbitrary_args(1, 2, 3)
    (1, 2, 3)
    <class 'tuple'>
    1
    2
    3
```

Arbitrary keyword arguments are taken as a dictionary:

```
>>> def func_with_arbitrary_kwargs(**kwargs):
...     print(kwargs)
...     print(type(kwargs))
...     for key in kwargs:
...         value = kwargs[key]
...         print(key, value)

>>> func_with_arbitrary_kwargs(name='Joe', size=10)
    {'name': 'Joe', 'size': 10}
    <class 'dict'>
    name Joe
    size 10
```

With this syntax, you can pass any list of arguments or dictionary of keyword arguments to your functions, and deal with these args/kwargs internally.

For example, you could add checks such as `if kwargs['shape'] == 'circle:'` to assert whch kind of shape your kwargs are describing, so you can deal with them accordingly.

Also, note that you can use unpacking of lists/tuples/dictionaries to make calling the functions even easier. Again this is done with asterisks, but on the function call instead of on the function definition:

```
>>> some_list = [1, 2, 3]
>>> func_with_arbitrary_args(*some_list)
# output ommited

>>> some_tuple = (1, 2, 3)    
>>> func_with_arbitrary_args(*some_tuple)
# output ommited

>>> some_dictionary = {'name': 'Joe', 'size': 10}
>>> func_with_arbitrary_kwargs(**some_dictionary)
# output ommited
```